# S-column with math subscript i

Tags: siunitx

The following MWE breaks, apparently because of the subscript `i` in `B_i`. After more trials, numbers (`0`-`9`) can't be subscripts either. If I change `i` to another letter, say `B_t`, then the document compiles fine.

The error message was

> ```
> ! Missing { inserted.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \c_math_toggle_token 
> l.7   $A_s$ & $B_i$ \\
> ```

Is this a bug of `siunitx`? I'm spotting some `expl3` syntax here. Perhaps the latter package has something to do with the error?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{SS}
  \toprule
  $A_s$ & $B_i$ \\
  \midrule 
  3.9 & 349.07 \\
  2.9 & 37.18 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

**A solution is found**: The document will compile if I enclose the subscript with braces, as in `B_{i}`. Nevertheless, I'm still interested in knowing **why** this phenomenon occurs.

Comment: Brace it: `{$A_s$}`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I found a similar solution, as I put in an edit, with braces around the subscript. I'd still like to know why this happens though.

Comment: `$A_s$` is not a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 4.6 “Tabular material” of the manual of `siunitx`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg for the answer! I still don't understand this: Why is `$B_i$` considered a (part of a) number?

Comment: @HerrK. `i` is the symbol for a complex root

Comment: @JosephWright: Ahhh, it totally escaped me. Thanks for the clarification!